# Crop image on left and right sides

Tags: php, image, gd

I have an image with dimensions `1440 X 500`.

I need to crop this image on the left at `200px` and right at `200px`. That is the new image must have dimensions of `1040 X 500`.

I am trying this

```
$original_w = 1440;
$original_h = 500;

$new_w = 1040;
$new_h = 500;

$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_w, $new_h);
imagecopyresampled($new_img, $original_img, 200, 0, 200, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $original_w, $original_h);
```

I have not obtained a desirable result, please help, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the integer coordinates.. the first two aren't the destination point?. in this case 0, 0 because you want from top left on the new image. do you get any error or the image is just not as you wish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), you're using `imagecopyresampled` wrong :

```
imagecopyresampled ( 
   resource $dst_image , 
   resource $src_image , 
   int $dst_x , 
   int $dst_y , 
   int $src_x , 
   int $src_y , 
   int $dst_w , 
   int $dst_h , 
   int $src_w , 
   int $src_h 
)
```

So :

```
$original_w = 1440;
$original_h = 500;

$new_w = 1040;
$new_h = 500;

$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_w, $new_h);
imagecopyresampled($new_img, $original_img, 0, 0, 200, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $new_w, $new_h);
```

Copying the 1040*500 box from (200,0) coords to the new image, at (0,0) coords.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably this:

`imagecopyresampled($new_img, $original_img, -200, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $original_w, $original_h);`

Which tells PHP to:

Copy the 1440x500 image starting at coordinate (0, 0) to a 1040x500 canvas starting at (-200, 0)

That way, you shift the original image 200 pixels left off of the canvas, and shrink the canvas width by 400px (so that the right 200px are also cut off).

I believe that should ge tyou what you're looking for.